# How to Login only via PayPal?

Tags: android, oauth, oauth-2.0, paypal

I'm using the Paypal Mobile Payments Library to enable the user to make a simple one-off payment on my android App.

I've got it all working fine using the code below. However, what I want is at the beginning of the app to just login via paypal, no payments at all, just login and authenticate such that later in the app (or even the next time the user opens the app) they will be already logged in and can make the payment without logging in.

```
PayPal paypalObject = PayPal.initWithAppID(getApplicationContext(), "APP-80W284485P519543T", PayPal.ENV_SANDBOX); // SANDBOX
CheckoutButton launchPayPalButton = paypalObject.getCheckoutButton(PaymentClass.this, PayPal.BUTTON_152x33, CheckoutButton.TEXT_PAY);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
launchPayPalButton.setLayoutParams(params);
launchPayPalButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        PayPalPayment newPayment = new PayPalPayment();
        newPayment.setSubtotal(BigDecimal.valueOf(_Order.getOrderObject().getPrice()));
        newPayment.setCurrencyType("GBP");
        newPayment.setRecipient("private@private.com");
        newPayment.setMerchantName("Private Ltd");
        Intent paypalIntent = PayPal.getInstance().checkout(newPayment, PaymentClass.this);
        startActivityForResult(paypalIntent, 1);
    }
});

((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.pyamentLinearLayout)).addView(launchPayPalButton, 0);
```

Comment: that's not a good idea. Can you think why?

Comment: because if the mobile got compromised, the app can be used to make many payments,etc.

However, that wouldn't add any security concerns as even with the normal payment that could happen since when you login, and make the payment, if you then make another booking, the app will keep your login session and the paypal button will actually show your name above the button and all. I just want to do this at the beginning of the app that's all.